# Finding html value with custom field in XML response using groovy in SOAPUI

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

In SOAPUI XML Response I have an element like below:

```
<div class="field-group aui-field-cascadingselect">
                       <label for="customfield_1">
                          Project
                          <span class="aui-icon icon-required">GitHmc</span>
                       </label>
                       <select class="select cascadingselect-parent" id="customfield_1" name="customfield_1">
                          <option class="default-option" value="">Task</option>
                          <option class="option-group-210" value="210">Task1</option>
                          <option class="option-group-813" value="813">Task2</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="213" selected="selected">Task3</option>
                          <option class="option-group-214" value="214">Task4</option>
                          <option class="option-group-215" value="215">Task5</option>
                          <option class="option-group-216" value="216">Task6</option>
                       </select>
                       <select class="select cascadingselect-child" id="customfield_1:1" name="customfield_1:1">
                          <option class="default-option" value="">Data</option>
                          <option class="option-group-210" value="">Data1</option>
                          <option class="option-group-813" value="">Data2</option>
                          <option class="option-group-211" value="">Data3</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="">Data4</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="417">Data5</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="1311">Data6</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="223">Data7</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="711">Data8</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="010" selected="selected">Data9</option>
                          <option class="option-group-213" value="410">Data10</option>
                       </select>
```

I need to get Value from selected option:

```
<option class="option-group-213" value="213" selected="selected">Task3</option>
```

and

```
<option class="option-group-213" value="010" selected="selected">Data9</option>
```

How can I get this 2 value using Groovy script?

Could someone please let me know how to make this work ?

Comment: looks it is html, not xml. Are you using http request test step?

Comment: yea. sorry. it is html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the XML using using `XmlParser`: http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html